# Why "C" code is working instead of putting an redeclaration error?

Tags: c, scope, variable-declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int var = 99;
    for (int var = 13; var == 13; var++)  // Why not putting up a variable redeclaration error here ?
        printf("Inside loop, var is = %d\n", var);
    printf("Outside loop, var is = %d\n", var);
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
Inside loop, var is = 13
Outside loop, var is = 99
```

This same confusion applies to functions also which are declared and defined in `main()`.

Comment: You mention functions at the end. Declaring and defining a function in `main` is a non-standard and non-portable C compiler extension. However the scoping of variables is standard.

Answer (score 3):

```
int var = 99;  // Outer scope
for(int var = 13; var == 13; var++)  // More inner scope
```

They're in different scopes. Variables can be declared in more inner scopes that have the same name as a variable in an outer scope. In that case, the inner declaration "shadows" the outer declaration. `var` will refer to the inner `var` within the loop while the inner `var` is in scope. Once the inner `var` goes out of scope, `var` will refer to the outer `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Scopes. You can define variables with the same name if they are inside different scopes. It is like name a variable `var` inside a separate function. It will still work.

It is unsafe however and it is better to have different names.

Inside each scope your program will use the variable defined in the scope if there are two variables with the same name.

Your for loop defines a new scope.

Comment: What's unsafe about it?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Arguably, it opens up accidentally referring to the wrong variable if you're careless.

Comment: It is easy to get lost and forget in which scope you are in, when designing large programs. I personally prefer to not do it. Safe habit.

Comment: You might want to explain that the `for` statement introduces a new scope that starts at the `(` and ends at the end of the for body. This is why you do not get an error: a separate `var` variable is defined for this scope, that shadows the one defined in the body of `main`.

Compiling with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra`) should produce a warning for a redefinition of a symbol that shadows a symbol of the same name in an outer scope. Add `-Wshadow` if you want just this warning.